# for loop is running only for the last element

Tags: office-js

```
const fruits = [' table.getColumnByName("ColumnF").getFilter()
.applyCustomFilter("Apple")',
'table.getColumnByName("ColumnF").getFilter()
.applyCustomFilter("orange")',
'table.getColumnByName("ColumnF").getFilter()
.applyCustomFilter("pears")'];

// Repeated process for each element
for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {repeating code here}
```

The above code is to filter the column with the specific fruit and run the repeated code. It should filter apple and run and repeat the code, filter away orange and run and repeat the code and filter pears and run the code but currently it is only filtering pears and running the repeated code 3 times for pears.

Comment: You need to provide the repeated code. Also, please specify what you expect to see and what you actually see. Why do you think it is only running for the pears?

Comment: You need 2 arrays to do this, one array containing ALL the information you want to sort thorugh, and a second array that contains all the fruit names.